# convert timezone in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, timezone

I want to convert "Asia/Singapore" timezone to "America/Virgin".

But `FindSystemTimeZoneById` is not include in windows phone 7 sdk. Is there any way to convert one timezone to other timezone ?

I can't write custom time zone converter because I don't know about daylight saving for timezone.

In WP7 SDK only include `TimeZoneInfo.Local` and `TimeZoneInfo.Utc`.

Comment: The question would be, why do you want to do this?

Comment: I am writing the app for meeting app. User can check what country is what time is now before they call the phone.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to do this, both Silverlight and Silverlight for Windows Phone 7 lack support for timezones. To perform this conversion you are going to have to grab a copy of the [tz databas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database)e and do it yourself.

I would recommend storing all your dates in UTC, then display in UTC or local time. Supporting arbitrary timezones is far too tricky!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you can try following workaround solution

```
TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - DateTime.UtcNow;

var systemTimeZone =  Math.Round(ts.TotalHours, 1); // this will gie time difference in double

var systemTimeZoneText = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(systemTimeZone).ToString("hh:mm tt"); // this will give result as 08:53 AM
```